# Type error when setting a jsPDF AcroFormRadioButton Subtype property

Tags: jspdf

I am trying to add a RadioButton to a PDF I am generating with jsPDF. I took the following code from the AcroForms example on the [jsPDF examples page](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/):

```
var radioGroup = new RadioButton();
radioGroup.value = "Test";
radioGroup.Subtype = "Form";
this.addField(radioGroup);
var radioButton1 = radioGroup.createOption("Test");
radioButton1.Rect = [50, 170, 30, 10];
radioButton1.AS = "/Test";
var radioButton2 = radioGroup.createOption("Test2");
radioButton2.Rect = [50, 180, 30, 10];
var radioButton3 = radioGroup.createOption("Test3");
radioButton3.Rect = [50, 190, 20, 10];
radioGroup.setAppearance(AcroForm.Appearance.RadioButton.Cross);
```

In my project I am getting this error at runtime on the third line of code where the RadioButton SubType property is being set to "Form":

> TypeError: Cannot set property Subtype of [object Object] which has only a getter

When I step through the example code (which does not give me that error) it does not appear that the property even gets set, it's null before and after the assignment. What does this property do? I don't see anything about it [in the docs](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-AcroForm-AcroFormRadioButton.html). Is it needed for my radio group to work correctly? If so, how do I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what that property does but I removed the line that tried to set it from my code and haven't found any issues with it yet.